# Laravel username with number if already taken

Tags: laravel, registration, user-registration

I'd like to make user registration so that if user register with name let's say "John" and this username is already taken he gets username "John2", and if "John2" is also taken he gets "John3" etc.

I could make some kind of loop to check if username is taken and generate a new one. But it is not efficient.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to know how marking a question as exact duplicate of another question. The question marked here is exactly the same but the selected answer is not the optimum answer. Yes, other answers gives a fair idea about how it can be approached. I have seen lots of questions marked as exact duplicate other questions, but they are not exact. I request the privileged users who mark questions as exact duplicate of other question can analyze all the answers of the other questions to know if it helps the OP to solve his problems. Thanks

Comment: @manian If you have an answer that you think is better than the answers in the duplicate, post it there. Duplicate questions are *supposed* to be closed, regardless of the quality of the answers on the existing question.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks @meagar for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Use this function: pass username in the param and get a unique name according to your DB

```
public function generateUniqueUserName($username)
    {
        $username = strtolower($username);
        $variations = 0;

        while (true) {
            $newUserName = $username;
            if ($variations > 0) {
                $newUserName .= (string) $variations;
            }
            $userExist = User::where('username', $newUserName)->exists();

            if ($userExist) {
                $variations++;
            } else {
                $username = $newUserName;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $username;
    }
```

Comment: That's pretty inefficient, you are quering inside a while true loop :/

Comment: We're all aware of what `while(true)` does, the problem is you should not be using it this way. On a busy site, for a generic username like "asdf", your `while(true)` might cause *a million queries* just to find a unique value.

Comment: if the user found then loop break then how to might cause a million queries?

Comment: Right, @ShaileshLadumor  once get unique username loop break.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below solution,

```
$username = \Str::slug('John');
$userRows  = User::whereRaw("username REGEXP '^{$username}([0-9]*)?$'")->pluck('username')->toArray();
if(count($userRows) > 0) {
  $userRows = str_replace($name, '', $userRows);
  $i=1;
  while(in_array($i, $userRows)) {
     $i++;
  }
  $username = $username.$i;
}
echo $username;
```

and add the below to your aliases array in config/app.php

```
'Str'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Str',
```

I assumed that you have 'User' Model, 'username' as your field and your are using 'slug'

Comment: Please let me know the reason for downvote to correct myself.

Comment: You've posted no explanation for the reasoning behind your solution. "Try below solution" is not a helpful explanation of why you think your solution is correct or better than any other, and it does nothing to help OP understand what it does.

Comment: Thanks @meagar for your response. I am not sure if every answer needs explanation. its pretty straight forward. I just want to help the OP to solve his problem quickly & I can explain him if he needs. With a negative vote, most of OP's dont even try the solution even if it solves their issue. Anyway I will post an explanation.